# To blur an element with no background image by css

Tags: html, css, blur

Using `background-image` on `body` tag and 
two `div`'s inside it.
I need to have blurred background for each
`div`.
what I can do now is to set `background-image` on
 each `div` and using `filter: blur` property to blur them.

but because I want the same background for whole page(not separated for each `div`),
 the way I want it to be is to set `background-image`
 on `body` tag and then blurring `div` elements.

That's what I've tried:

```
body {
    background-image: url(public/images/billy-huynh-W8KTS-mhFUE-unsplash\ \(1\).jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
}

.parent-div::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    filter: blur(5px);

}

.parent-div {
    position: relative;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<body>
<div class=" parent-div">
    <div class=" child-div">
        <h4 class=" text-light">Hello world!!</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class=" parent-div">
    <div class=" child-div">
        <h4 class=" text-light">Hello world!!</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

In fact, I want to blur `div` elements with no background image.
Is there a way to do so? 
thanks

Comment: Can u share us the HTML code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`backdrop-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter)

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/174/800/800.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  margin:0;
  position: relative;
}


.parent-div {
  position: relative;
  height:50vh;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class=" parent-div">
  <div class=" child-div">
    <h4 class=" text-light">Hello world!!</h4>
  </div>
</div>
<div class=" parent-div">
  <div class=" child-div">
    <h4 class=" text-light">Hello world!!</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Yasin You can mark this answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/) to indicate this answer solved your problem.